# ease transition all except one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the below in place because I would like to transition all content with an ease.

```
*{transition:all .5s ease}
```

But I have came across just one element I do NOT want to transition...

I have tried defining a class called '.no-transition' and none important across..

```
.notransition {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

I added said class directly to the element I didn't want to transition.

This didn't work.. I also tried added the class to the element with jQuery, but appears..

`*{transition:all .5s ease}` still override ever attempt.

I would rather not go into every element and have a transition on class... I would prefer target just the one.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just negate the class using the [`:not` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not):

```
*:not(.notransition) {
    transition:all .5s ease;
}
```

Now all elements will be transitioned, except those with class `notransition`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rg78v8uL/)